# Semantic UI vertical divider no text

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I'm trying to use a semantic UI divider like so:

`<div class="ui vertical divider" style="left:87.5%"></div>`

However, as you can see from the [documentation](https://semantic-ui.com/elements/divider.html), when using keywords `horizontal` or `vertical`, spacing is included for text.

Does anyone know if it's possible to use a vertical divider without the spacing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use vertical dividers without text but you can make grids divided which contain no text https://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html#special-grids

Comment: Neat solution. Cheers.